# Перевод точки или геометрии из postgis в 2gis (или обратно)

Tags: python, django, geocoding, postgis, 2gis-api

Мне нужно найти объекты на полигоне, обозначенном на карте. С фронта мне передаются точки с карты 2GIS, формата `(lat, long)`, обозначающие точки полигона. В базе данных лежат точки postGIS, формата `0101000020E6100000A089B0E1E98548404E0CC9C9C4EF4B40`. Мне нужно их свести к единому формату, желательно postGIS, чтобы найти все точки из базы данных, лежащие внутри полигона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения задачи не обязательно приводить всё к единому формату. Можно сразу работать с этим полем как с геометрией.
 Более важно, чтобы ваши точки из 2Gis и точки из PostGis были в одной системе координат.
 
Уточните этот момент, если потребуется приведите к единой.
 
После этого можно сразу делать выборку:
 
В запросе строим полигон из точек 2Gis (geometry B), выбираем все точки таблицы PostGis (geometry A) принадлежащие полигону

```
ST_Within(geometry A, geometry B)
```

Comment: Этот вариант помог, действительно они свелись сами с помощью `ST_PointFromText('Point(lat long)')`. Единственной проблемой было то, что координаты были не в одной системе, поэтому объекты в Набережных челнах оказывались в океане неподалеку от Китая. Через несколько часов помог просто свап осей (с "lat long" на "long lat").

Answer (score 0):

**postGIS -> долгота / широта**

Используйте `ST_AsText` для просмотра объекта:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(the_geom) FROM myTable;
```

Для просмотра x и y используйте такой запрос:

```
SELECT ST_X(the_geom), ST_Y(the_geom), ST_AsText(the_geom) FROM myTable;
```

Этот и другие варианты можно посмотреть в обсуждении на stackexchange:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42970/getting-coordinates-from-geometry-in-postgis